# Not able to replace checkboxes Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a mozilla add on for a web page. Using the attached Javascript code I am able to create checkbox. The checkbox should replace with other checkbox depending on the selected value in dropdown. Onclick on dropdown I am calling fun_sub_cat function which is creating checkbox and also replacing but it replace only once. For eg: If there are 2 option in dropdown 1 and 2, Selecting option 1 checkbox values should 1,2,3 and for option 2 checkbox values should be a,b,c.

On Click function it creates checkbox and changing the value for the first time replaces the checkbox value as well however when I click 3rd time on dropdown or change the value, it does not work. It attains the 2nd time changed checkbox values.

```js
var k = 0;
    function fun_cat_sub() {
    console.log("Value Changed");
    var Myarry = "";
        if(document.getElementById('sub_cat').value == 'Password Reset'){
            Myarry = check_list1;
              if(k == 0){
                console.log("creating checkbox for the first time");
                k = k+1;
                for (var i = 0; i < Myarry.length; i++) {
                    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                    checkbox.id = "checkBox"+i;
                    checkbox.value = Myarry[i];
                    checkbox.class = "_class";
                    checkbox.appendAfter(br_3);
                    var lab_chk = document.createElement('label');
                    lab_chk.innerHTML = Myarry[i];
                    lab_chk.id = "lab_chk"+i;
                    lab_chk.value = Myarry[i];
                    lab_chk.style.marginLeft = "10px";
                    lab_chk.appendAfter(checkbox);
                    document.createElement('br').appendAfter(lab_chk);
                }
              }
            else if(k != 0){
              console.log("I am in 1st Loop");
              checking(Myarry);
            }
          }
        else {
            Myarry = check_list2;
            console.log("I am in 2nd Loop");
            checking(Myarry);
        }
    }

    function checking(Myarry){
      console.log(Myarry.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < Myarry.length; i++) {
        var old_chk = document.getElementById('checkBox'+i);
        var new_chk = document.createElement("input");
        new_chk.type = "checkbox";
        new_chk.id = "checkBox"+i;
        new_chk.value = Myarry[i];
        old_chk.parentNode.replaceChild(new_chk, old_chk);
        var old_lab_chk = document.getElementById('lab_chk'+i);
        var new_lab_chk = document.createElement('label');
        new_lab_chk.innerHTML = Myarry[i];
        new_lab_chk.style.marginLeft = "10px";
        old_lab_chk.parentNode.replaceChild(new_lab_chk, old_lab_chk);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: We're going to need the HTML against which this code is running, in addition to a *manifest.json*, which tells us in what context it is running (e.g. popup, in a web page, etc.)

Comment: So far, what you have in the question appears to not depend on any extension API's. Thus, you should be able to add enough to the snippet so we can see exactly what's happening.